# YA book. Planet in our solar system. Two teenagers sealed in a plant with flashlight. Oxygen from photosynthesis saves their lives

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, planets

The two teenagers are walking across the planet to warn their parents of an evil plan by a major company.

They are wearing pressure suits. They are running out of oxygen. The boys spend the night sealed inside a huge alien plant that seals up overnight.

One boy cannot bring himself to turn off their flashlight even though he feels he is wasting the batteries.

The flashlight being on saves them! The inside of the leaves they are sealed inside undergoes photosynthesis in the artificial light. This produces enough oxygen to save their lives.

Comment: Either massive deja vu or this has been asked here before.  I re-read it as a result of seeing a very similar question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Red Planet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Planet_(novel)) by Robert Heinlein

> When Jim and Frank sneak into Howe's office and rescue Willis, the
> bouncer repeats two overheard conversations between Howe and Beecher,
> the unscrupulous colonial administrator of Mars, detailing Beecher's
> plans for Willis and for the colony. When Beecher learns Howe has a
> bouncer, he is ecstatic; the London Zoo is willing to pay a hefty
> price for a specimen. **Worse, Beecher has secretly planned to prevent
> the annual migration of the colonists** (to avoid 12 months of severe
> winter weather) in order to save money. **The boys run away from school
> to warn their parents and the colony.**

---

> The boys set out to skate the thousands of miles on the frozen Martian
> canals to their homes. During the trip, Frank gets sick. **On the third
> night, they are forced to take shelter inside a giant Martian
> cabbage-plant (nearly suffocating when it folds up at night).**

Comment: No problem!  Come back with more questions

Comment: Years after reading it, I thought to do the calculation. Optimistically, two people keeping very still will have 50W metabolism each, so 100W. 100W light output is ridiculous for a flashlight, perhaps 3 orders of magnitude too high. And then, photosynthesis is <5% efficient, the flashlight isn't perfect either, and much of the light is absorbed by the boys' clothing and equipment. Maybe a 10 kW flashlight would be enough, except it would cook cabbage and boys.

Comment: @JohnDoty, remember that this was written in the era of incandescent bulbs.  10W would not be unreasonable for such a bulb; a lantern battery could power it all night.  Assuming Martian photosynthesis is more efficient (and broader-spectrum) to compensate for the lower light level, it's borderline possible.

Comment: @Mark Even if Martian photosynthesis and the flashlight are both 100% efficient, 10W is much less than 100W.

Comment: I think the OP is misremembering. The plant didn't give them oxygen - their flashlight caused it to close around them which kept them warm. Oxygen wasn't the issue

Comment: @Andrew There's a discussion of this when the boys are examined by their doctor following their journey. The doctor says "by all rights you two should have smothered." But after they mention the flashlight he says "the flashlight saved your lives, son." He explicitly talks about photosynthesis making the necessary oxygen. But Heinlein obviously never calculated how much light it would take.

Comment: Thanks.  Clearly a book I need to reread

Comment: Having reread the book, it's important to note that not that much oxygen would be needed, since the Mars of "Red Planet" already has enough oxygen that a human who is adapted to high-altitude life could survive without any gear at all; all the boys need is a respirator that (somehow) concentrates the oxygen already in the atmosphere so they get a bit more pressure then the planet naturally supplies (when they travel in an open air vehicle at high speed the motion raises the pressure of air enough that they don't need masks).

Answer (score 8):

Red Planet by Robert A Heinlein.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Planet_(novel)):

*Mars has been colonized by humans, but is governed by an administrator appointed by an Earth-based company - the colonists have no political power. Colonial teenagers Jim Marlowe and Frank Sutton travel to the Lowell Academy boarding school for the start of the academic year.*

*Beecher, the unscrupulous colonial administrator of Mars... has secretly planned to prevent the annual migration of the colonists (to avoid 12 months of severe winter weather) in order to save money.*

*The boys set out to skate the thousands of miles on the frozen Martian canals to their homes. During the trip, Frank gets sick. On the third night, they are forced to take shelter inside a giant Martian cabbage-plant (nearly suffocating when it folds up at night)*

...The flashlight saves them from suffocation...

There's also a major plotline revolving around Jim's pet - a native Martian lifeform known as a "bouncer"

Comment: Thank you. This is correct. I accepted the other answer.